# Apply S-Domain Notch to Time Signal

Tags: signal-processing, band-pass, digital-filter

- I have a signal in time domain which shows an 8Hz oscillation.
- I've designed a notch (band-stop) filter in frequency domain (S domain) to
  filter this 8Hz oscillation.
- Notch design parameters are Width, Depth and Attenuation
- How can I apply this S domain notch to my time signal?

PS: I have Matlab Signal Processing Toolbox.

Comment: If you're using Matlab, you have a sampled, and thus discrete time signal, not a continuous time signal. You need to convert your s domain filter to the z domain, which will give you some IIR filter. Alternatively, you can design some FIR filter instead. Then you can use something like the filter command in matlab to apply your filter to your signal.

Comment: Are the signals and the s-domain filter already read into matlab variables ? If so, you can look at `tf`, `filter`, `c2d`, `filtfilt`, `lsim` etc. Matlab will do the continuous time to discrete time conversion itself when certain functions are used.

Comment: Build it and connect your signal to the input and your output will be the filtered version of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing @LetterSized and @AJN answers in a 2 lines Matlab code:

```
% x: Time domain signal with 8Hz frequency content 
% tf: Notch filter transfer function in S domain

TF_d = c2d(TF, Ts, 'tustin');
xfilt = filter(tf_d.Numerator, tf_d.Denominator, x);
```

Comment: That won't give you the designed response.  `filtfilt` puts the signal through the filter twice.

Comment: Thanks! Replaced `filtfilt` with `filter` as per your comment.